Partion on bootdrive looking to combine back into one
Sorry I don't exactly know how to describe what happened but it looks like my boot drive is installed on a partition. I would like to combine the partition back so I don't have limited space.
Here is what it looks like when I run sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
nvme0n1                               465.8G
├─nvme0n1p1               vfat          512M /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               ext4            1G /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               LVM2_member 464.3G
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4          200G /
nvme1n1                   ntfs        465.8G /mnt/69D813F4795B680E               500GB Drive

Honestly I'm just a little confused becuase the main drive has 195.80Gb when it should be having 500Gb.
Anyway to do this without reinstalling the OS?
Thanks and sorry for the vagueness of the question.
